# Delay in class change to 'activated' when using ng-click in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ng-click on a div element in an ionic app as such:

```
<div class="thediv" ng-click="showActionsheet()"><p>26</p></div>
```

This works well, but I have some CSS setup:

```
.thediv.activated {
    background-color: #d18027;
    border: 2px solid #ffc666;
}
```

The CSS activates if I press the div long enough, but when I just tap it nothing happens.  I would also like to keep it activated until the actionsheet closes.  Not sure how to go about that either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't solve the delay. That's one of the bad things of working with building hybrid mobile apps. Ionic framework is very good, but **in my opinion** it will never be as fast as native apps (mainly if it's not a very new-fast-modern device).

About keeping it activated, you can create a variable like `$scope.isActivated` and at the beginning of your method `showActionsheet()` give it a `true`. When you close the action sheet set it to `false`.

And in your div you can do something like

```
<div class="thediv" ng-click="showActionsheet()" ng-class="active: isActivated"><p>26</p></div>
```

In your CSS do also

```
.thediv.activated,
.thediv.active, {
    background-color: #d18027;
    border: 2px solid #ffc666;
}
```